# function inside a function project online Odata url query

Tags: odata, project-online

I am trying to create a Project Online OData URL where I use two functions, one inside the other `$filter=substring(ResourceName, indexof(ResourceName,','),10) eq 'example'`

substring is the first function and index of is the second function called inside the substring brackets and it returns an integer.

so, I get this message back:

```
Fehler beim Verarbeiten dieser Anforderung.
```

and I just want to know why and whether I can do the same some other way

Comment: Does the server fully support OData substring and indexof functions? Be aware of indexof('','') which can return -1 if the first string does not contain the second string. -1 cannot be used in substring. Do you want to achieve this in one request?

Comment: there is no documentation for the api or not enough, so its not possible to check if the server supports it, and yes ideally in one request...